# Django-ViewFlow: How to add CRUD views to flow

Tags: django, django-viewflow

I've recently come across the Viewflow library for Django which I appears to be a very powerful tool for creating complex workflows.

My app is a simple ticketing system were the workflow is started by creating a Ticket, then a user should be able to create zero or more WorkLog's associated with the ticket via a CRUD page(s), similar to the standard Django admin change_list/detail.

What should the template for the list view look like? I would like to have the UI integrated into the library's frontend.

The flow clearly utilises the following views:

1) CreateView for Ticket

2a) ListView of WorkLog's, template has controls 'back', 'add' (goes to step 2b), 'done' (goes to step 3).

2b) CreateView for WorkLog

3) End

Code:

models.py:

```
class TicketProcess(Process):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    planned = models.BooleanField()

    worklogs = models.ForeignKey('WorkLog', null=True)


class WorkLog(models.Model):
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=150)
```

views.py:

```
class WorkLogListView(FlowListMixin, ListView):

    model = WorkLog


class WorkLogCreateView(FlowMixin, CreateView):

    model = WorkLog
    fields = '__all__'
```

flows.py:

```
from .views import WorkLogCreateView
from .models import TicketProcess

@frontend.register
class TicketFlow(Flow):
    process_class = TicketProcess

    start = (
        flow.Start(
            CreateProcessView,
            fields = ['title', 'category', 'description', 'planned']
        ).Permission(
            auto_create=True
        ).Next(this.resolution)
    )

    add_worklog = (
        flow.View(
            WorkLogListView
        ).Permission(
            auto_create=True
        ).Next(this.end)
    )

    end = flow.End()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that in a different view, or in the same view, just don't call `activation.done` on a worklog adding request. You can do it by checking what button was pressed in the request.POST data.

```
@flow.flow_view
def worklog_view(request):
    request.activation.prepare(request.POST or None, user=request.user)
    if '_logitem' in request.POST:
         WorkLog.objects.create(...)
    elif request.POST:
        activation.done()
        request.activation.done()
        return redirect(get_next_task_url(request, request.activation.process))
    return render(request, 'sometemplate.html', {'activation': request.activation})
```